# Ubuntu 18.04 EM7455 works only after suspend

Tags: 18.04, laptop, usb-modem, 4g

I hit a strange problem discussed in this thread of some modem mailing lis https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/modemmanager-devel/2017-February/003804.html.

Basically when I start up my system in logs I get messages that modem can't be activated because 'No SIM card inserted'. Also, when I'm doing mmcli -L I get

```
Found 1 modems:
        /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Sierra] MBIM [1199:9079]
```

And when I do mmcli -m 0 I get

```
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Sierra'
           |          model: 'MBIM [1199:9079]'
           |       revision: 'SWI9X30C_02.30.03.00'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts, lte'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts, lte'
           |   equipment id: '014582005392668'
 -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'unknown'
           | unlock retries: 'unknown'
           |          state: 'failed'
           |  failed reason: 'sim-missing'
           |    power state: 'low'
           |    access tech: 'unknown'
           | signal quality: '0' (cached)
```

My modem manager is good to go and should work with MBIM.

```
borowis@NoName:~$ dpkg -l modemmanager
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-==========================================================
ii  modemmanager               1.6.8-2ubuntu1     amd64              D-Bus service for managing modems
```

But if I close the lid and my laptop goes to suspend mode, than I open lid back again everything works as expected. My modem is now:
mmcli -L

```
Found 1 modems:
        /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [Sierra] MBIM [1199:9079]
```

Sim card is good to go mmcli -m 1

```
  -------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: '014582005392668'
           |  enabled locks: 'fixed-dialing'
           |    operator id: '25501'
           |  operator name: 'Vodafone UA'
           |   subscription: 'unknown'
           |   registration: 'home'
```

I can connect to the internet, issue AT commands etc. Another interesting thing is that I've got to close and open the lid, doing # systemctl restart ModemManager doesn't cut it.

Seems like I hit a bug with modemmanager/libqmi/whatever? Do you know what can/should be done in situations like this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem (sierra modem, Thinkpad X240, Ubuntu 18.04) but in my case it is counterwise – ModemManager stops working after suspending (closing the lid) three times in row. After that I cannot suspend anymore. 
When it happens mmcli -L gives:

```
Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/9 [Sierra] MBIM [1199:A001]
```

And mmcli -m 9:

```
  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3)'
           |          state: 'registered'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'gprs, lte'
           | signal quality: '0' (cached)
```

At first glance restarting ModemManager (sudo service ModemManager restart or systemcl) doesn't resolve the problem. After restarting ModemManager, mmcli -L:

```
Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Sierra] MBIM [1199:A001]
```

mmcli -m 0:

```
 Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3)'
           |          state: 'registered'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'lte'
           | signal quality: '0' (cached)
```

But if I wait a few seconds till ModemManager indicator shows up and then click connect, indicator disappears for a moment and starts loading and connecting once again and this time it starts working properly.

```
Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [Sierra] MBIM [1199:A001]

mmcli -m 1:

  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3)'
           |          state: 'connected'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'lte'
           | signal quality: '0' (cached)
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 ModemManager used to work flawlessly.

Comment: yeah, looks to me like some kind of delay issue